# Are these three dimensional arrays legal in C?

Tags: c, arrays

My professor’s final exam mostly consisted of very tricky syntax. For example, some of his questions were like "use pointer 1 to print out the letter k without using brackets. Luckily it was open book.

So one question was:

```
int a[2][2][2] = {{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}};
```

write a printf statement that will print out "7910". **Using pointers without using square brackets.**

At first, I thought this was a typo or an illegal array. I thought the array is supposed to stop at the third array from the left.

I wrote:

```
printf("%d%d%d\n",*(*(a+1)+1)),*(*(a+2)),*(*(a+2)));
```

I put this because if the array was

```
int a[2][2] = {{7,8},{11,12}};
```

a syntax similar would work.

So was this a typo? If not, what is the right syntax?

Comment: This is actually a bad initializer syntax, and is a constraint violation if I am not mistaken...

Comment: All in all, it's bad C Good enough for an EE class I suppose. .

Comment: The array initialisation is a syntax error in MSVC ~ *error C2078: too many initializers.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Only some warnings on GCC

Comment: MSVC does compile it when it has more `{ braces }` such as `int a[2][2][2] = {{{5,6}, {7,8}}, {{9,10}, {11,12}}}; ` (as just answered by @haccks below).

Comment: `a` holds a pointer to the base of the array so if you cast it to `(int*)` you can simply add to it like this `printf("%d%d%d",*(int*)a+2,*(int*)a+4,*(int*)a+5);`

Comment: @WeatherVane; MSVC uses visual C and that is not standard. Standard C allows this.

Comment: @haccks that is well known but what is your point in this case? Oh you just edited the comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane; It is not a typo and is a valid syntax, though not preferable :)

Comment: @haccks certainly misleading (the posted code)! Not the worst offence of MSVC to disallow it.

Comment: @WeatherVane; Can't agree more.

Comment: I am just wandering - what is the reason of such a exam questions? It does not make any sense - they should learn how to create safe and efective algorithms - not to solve stupid puzzles. Your professor should read a book "How to teach programming" and "how to teach C"

Comment: The exam question "Write a printf statement that will print out "7910" using pointers without using square brackets can be answered with `printf("%s", "7910");`

Answer (score 5):

Compiler, in most cases, will parse the above initialization as

```
int a[2][2][2] = { { {5,6}, {7,8} }, 
                   { {9,10}, {11,12} }
                 };
```

This will also work if you will write it as

```
int a[2][2][2] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

but this is really not a good practice.

C standard says about it
§6.7.9(p17):

> When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union<sup>149)</sup>. [...]

p26

> EXAMPLE 3 The declaration
>
> ```
> int y[4][3] = {
>     { 1, 3, 5 },
>     { 2, 4, 6 },
>     { 3, 5, 7 },
> };
> ```
>
> is a definition with a fully bracketed initialization: `1`, `3`, and `5` initialize the first row of `y` (the array object `y[0]`), namely `y[0][0]`, `y[0][1]`, and `y[0][2]`. Likewise the next two lines initialize `y[1]` and `y[2]`. The initializer ends early, so `y[3]` is initialized with zeros. **Precisely the same effect could have been achieved by**
>
> ```
> int y[4][3] = {
>     1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7
> };
> ```
>
> The initializer for `y[0]` does not begin with a left brace, so three items from the list are used. Likewise the next three are taken successively for `y[1]` and `y[2]`.

Comment: Is this a C peculiarity or does it apply to C++? Compilers seem to disallow it in C++.

Comment: Clang understands it as: `{{{5,6}}, {{7,8}}}` apparently... I don’t think it’s valid C anyway.

Comment: Even `gcc` is giving "only" 7 warning on this line.

Comment: @DeiDei; This stand for C++ too. See section § 8.5.1 para 10 and 11.

Comment: @EugeneSh.; Compile it with option `-std=c11`.

Comment: See example 6 (p. 29) of that section, which seems to me to explain the behaviour noted by @idmean, including a diagnostic for too many initialisers.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
int a[2][2][2] = {{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}};
```

is not valid C and a compiler should report a diagnostic message.

According to C11 N1570, §6.7.9/20 *Initialization*:

> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are
>   aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the
>   subaggregates or contained unions. **If the initializer of a
>   subaggregate** or contained union **begins with a left brace, the
>   initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace
>   initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate** or the
>   contained union.

The problem is that `{{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}}` attempts to initialize *four* elements of the most outer array object (i.e. `a` represents array of array array of `int`), while its size has been *explicitely* stated as two:

```
int a[2][2][2] = {{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}};
      |           |      |      |       |
      |           |      |      |       |
      -----------------------------------
```

This is constraint violation, as by subclause §6.7.9/2:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not
>   contained within the entity being initialized.

It *would be* valid if you omit its first size, as shown below:

```
int a[][2][2] = {{5,6}, {7,8}, {9,10}, {11,12}};
```

which is effectively the same as:

```
int a[4][2][2] = {
    {
        {5, 6},
        {0, 0}
    },
    {
        {7, 8},
        {0, 0}
    },
    {
        {9, 10},
        {0, 0}
    },
    {
        {11, 12},
        {0, 0}
    }  
};
```

Note that you may initialize it as:

```
int a[2][2][2] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; // legal, but not advisable
```

or even:

```
int a[2][2][2] = {{5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}; // bad style
```

This is allowed by remaining sentence of the mentioned §6.7.9/20:

> **Otherwise**, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account
>   for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of
>   the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize
>   the next element or member of the aggregate of which the current
>   subaggregate or contained union is a part.